# SEG operator in .com files

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

Why we can't convert .exe to .com file using exe2bin if in code we have command like `mov <register>, SEG <variable name>`? What could the SEG operator return if there were no error?

Comment: A .com file may not use segments, the registers are initialized before the program start running.

Comment: a DOS COM file is loaded into single segment from offset 0x100 (thus maximum size of COM binary is 65536-256 = 65280 bytes). All 8086 segment registers `cs, ds, es, ss` are pointing to this initial segment. You of course *CAN* use segments in com files too, if you decide so, in the PSP area you can find upper memory limit, and everything between initial segment and upper limit is playground area for your code. But the EXE does load data into separate segment, and `mov r16,SEG var` will compile as `mov r16,imm16` where the immediate constant is relocated to point to the data segment after load.

Comment: I.e. EXE file contains various sections and meta data, which can't be simply (machine-like) converted to flat binary without any relocation (that's what .com is, raw machine code bytes loaded from offset 0x100, and executing the first byte of it - makes common problem to beginners if they put their data at the beginning of COM file, they get them executed as instructions instead of their code entry-point). If you have the source code of EXE file (and it fits into single segment), you can probably adjust it to have variables in code segment with just few [but important] code changes.